# Analytics tab empty in Worklight Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-console, worklight-analytics

I've added an analytics server (Linux, accessible from the http:///iwap/worklight/v1/index.html) to use with my Worklight 6 server, but, the "Analytics" tab is now displaying, but, is empty.

The changed the wl.analytics.url under the war configuration for "Environment entries for web modules" and restarted the app.

The Worklight V6 Information Center (under "Installing and configuring the IBM Websphere Analytics PLatform"|"Configuring Worklight Server for analytics") says to use the format "http://<>iwap/v1/events/_bulk, but, the description column in the "Environment entries for web modules" settings says to use "http:///iwap/v1/events/app_activities".  I've tried both, both with same result, empty screen under the Analytics tab.

Not sure where to go at this point, any one set this up successfully?

Comment: The <>/ above contain my internal servers ip address

Comment: "Environment entries for web modules" settings says to use "http:///iwap/v1/events/app_activities" -  This is an error that will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

**http://${iwap.server.path}/iwap/v1/events/_bulk**

If the analytics tab is blank, its possible that your IWAP server is not currently running or is unreachable from your worklight server.

In truth, the analytics tab just acts as an iFrame. You can visit the analytics console using the URL:

**http://${iwap.server.path}/iwap/worklight/v1/index.html**

If you are unable to visit that link, then the issue is with your IWAP server. Make sure that the server is started using the command "service analytics start" on the IWAP machine.

Comment: Found the issue, as the ip used for the analytics server is internal, it was assumed this was analytics server doesn't have to be externally faced (there is no doc in this requirement).  Some additional information that this is a simple iFrame would be helpful...  Thanks for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address you enter is the IP address of the analytics server you installed independently of the Worklight server.  Have you done this?

[Installing and Configuring the analytics platform](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/install_config/t_install_websphere_analytics_platform.html)

The analytics tab in the Worklight console simply shows an iframe, using a slightly modified URL from the one you entered in the configuration.  If you entered

`http://<>/iwap/v1/events/_bulk` (this the correct URL)

The URL you can visit is

`http://<>/iwap/worklight/v1/index.html`

You said you can visit it directly.  Can you view the network tab or console in Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see if the URL it is attempting to visit from the Worklight console is correct?

Comment: The URL directly to the analytics server works fine, but, the resulting Analytics tab in Worklight console is empty.  The IP address is used (http://<>/iwap/v1/events/_bulk) is for the analytics server.