# Where is my worklight.properties file?

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

I have been looking for my worklight.properties file and the only property file is in the application center folder. In there all of the properties are commented out. However, there is a /tmp/migration- and some numbers that also have the worklight properties which seems to have some information in it. Does anyone know where I can get this file and or where to copy the worklight.property files on my liberty server so that the server sees it?

Thanks!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8nul8kiquzpl5r/analyticsserver.xml?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pog4e73s1efl5wv/defaultServer1.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

The file is on your worklight project on the studio at:
/server/conf/worklight.properties

And also inside of the generated WAR file of your project that is used for the runtime. 
at: WEB-INF/classes/conf

The WAR file is under the "bin" folder of the project.

Some clarifications based on the questions around Analytics:
1 - It is a handled by second war file that can be run in a isolated server, a minimal config could be for example:
server.xml:(For analytics server, not a production config.)

```
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              host="localhost"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" />

<application context-root="/analytics"
         id="analytics"
         location="analytics.war"
         name="analytics"
         type="war">
  <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
</application>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/shards" value="1" />
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/replicas_per_shard" value="1" />
</server>
```

For production setup take a look on this page: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/t_setting_up_production_cluster.html

The analytics tool requires that the application will  opt-in on its use, this can be done by the worklight.properties or via JNDI definition on the server with the application runtime(usually known as "/worklight" application)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html

Here, the property to be set could be this for example:

```
...
 <application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="InvokeAdapterProcedure.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
            <privateLibrary>
                <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
            </privateLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Worklight project runtime. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='"http"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/publicWorkLightPort" value='"10080"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"SampleRuntime"'/>
...
```

-> code above just as a illustration of an App that has the context root as "worklight", therefor its jndi properties start as "worklight/".
-> this property:

```
<jndiEntry value="http://<analytics server IP>:9080/analytics/data" jndiName="worklight/wl.analytics.url"/>
</server>
```

This property will guide the application to know to where send the info and also the worklight console to where to send the information to be stored.

In case, you have problems to see data on the analytics console, ensure that the application is aware of the Analytics Tool, by cheking if there is a icon for the "Analytics Dashboard", on the top-right of the table list of applications.

Also, check if the analytics is set properly as either been "master" and have a "data" node defined, or having both behaviors by not having  "analytics/nodetype" jndi property set(therefore, acting as both).

Hope this update, helps in your problem.

Comment: If you use the WAR assembled by the studio it should contains the file you search.  Then you can use the configuration tool from worklight to help you deploy it into production server.

Comment: It was the war file that came with the server. In particular the analytics.war file. I have created a second server and pointed the jndi to the analyticsData tab in the location of my first server. IT seems according to the files there is some data there but its not picking anything up on the anayltics server.

Comment: Is this ( http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_installation.html ) what you are trying to do? To install the analytics war? Could you  provide your more details? What's your server version?

Comment: Maybe this older question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467061/analytics-tab-empty-in-worklight-console

Comment: Cesar I am trying to link my analytics console from my second server called analytics to my defaultServer which has the application on it. The analytics console shows up but I don't see any data. I did also get the analytics console to work on my current server but again, I don't see any data. I have no worklight.property file so I can't put the wl.analytics url in there. I am using WL 6.2.0.1 I am sharing the files via dropbox. any help is apprecaited and again I don't have a worklight.properties file. These servers were started by bin/server create

Comment: Uploaded to question. I really appreciate if you can help me further by looking at the files

Comment: Does the application that is on the server need the wl.analytics url?

Comment: Ceasar, We added the analytics url to the WLNATIVESALES war file and uploaded it to the Worklight console. I added:

wl.analytics.url=http://IP/WLNativeSales360/data
wl.analytics.logs.forward=true
wl.analytics.username=admin
wl.analytics.password=admin


But the warfile with those settings isn't sitting on the server itself (the new war). Only deployed to the worklight console. If settings are added to the war file does the runtime have to be deployed again?

Does the analytifcs URL that is on the war file point to the analytics war file?

Comment: WLNativeSales is where we want to get data from

Comment: Yes, the if you change the worklight.properties. The war must be reployed, there is a choice on the server configuration tool, that does this for you. Or you can use the ant scripts for it.  
     
Either way, you need to replace the war in the server, so the runtime of the worklight can see this properties update. Anything that is the "classes" and "server" folder from the project requires a redeploy.

Comment: Hope that this last info update helps you, It tried to provided more details around setting up the analytics not in the application runtime server, in your first sample xml of the "defaultServer1.xml" , you was adding the analytics in the same server as the application runtime.  You only need to set the  wl.analytics.url there, not the application **<application context-root="/analytics"**.